# How can I avoid breaking Postgres sync replication when building a large index?

Tags: postgresql, replication

We have pairs of Postgres 9.2 servers using synchronous replication. Sometimes rebuilding an index on a large table will break replication due to WAL segments not being kept around long enough. We are a bit constrained for space so don't want to allocate a bunch more for WAL segments.

Is there any way to build the index "incrementally" instead of in one big transaction? Any other ways we could handle this?

Comment: I should mention that the tables in question are not in use when the index is built.

Comment: You must enable WAL archiving. It's really required for reliable streaming replication prior to 9.4.

Comment: We have done that. The issue is that if a tx takes long enough (like 30 mins) then we don't have enough segments archived and it all falls over. The long tx's are building indexes.

Comment: Unfortunately there aren't really any better solutions before 9.4's replication slots - and all replication slots do is make sure the master holds on to enough WAL for all existing replicas. That can cause the master to run out of disk space in `pg_xlog`. So it's just a different trade-off. What you really want sounds like slowing the master down so the replica can keep up, but that's not supported AFAIK. Partial/progressive index builds certainly aren't, and I'm not sure they'd help anyway. We looked at adding rate-limited index builds but it didn't make it to 9.4.

Comment: Tx for all the info. So for now we need more disk space or bust :)